# Gradient of Image in PyTorch - for Gradient Penalty calculation in WGAN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I am following this [Github Repo](https://github.com/amanchadha/coursera-gan-specialization/blob/main/C1%20-%20Build%20Basic%20Generative%20Adversarial%20Networks/Week%203/C1W3_WGAN_GP.ipynb) for the WGAN implementation with Gradient Penalty.

And I am trying to understand the following method, which does the job of unit-testing the gradient-penalty calulations.

```py
def test_gradient_penalty(image_shape):
    bad_gradient = torch.zeros(*image_shape)
    bad_gradient_penalty = gradient_penalty(bad_gradient)
    assert torch.isclose(bad_gradient_penalty, torch.tensor(1.))

    image_size = torch.prod(torch.Tensor(image_shape[1:]))
    good_gradient = torch.ones(*image_shape) / torch.sqrt(image_size)
    good_gradient_penalty = gradient_penalty(good_gradient)
    assert torch.isclose(good_gradient_penalty, torch.tensor(0.))

    random_gradient = test_get_gradient(image_shape)
    random_gradient_penalty = gradient_penalty(random_gradient)
    assert torch.abs(random_gradient_penalty - 1) < 0.1

# Now pass tuple argument for image dimenstion of 
# (batch_size, channel, height, width)
test_gradient_penalty((256, 1, 28, 28))
```

#### I don't understand the below line

`good_gradient = torch.ones(*image_shape) / torch.sqrt(image_size)`

In above the `torch.ones(*image_shape)` is just filling a 4-D Tensor filled up with 1 and then
`torch.sqrt(image_size)` is just representing the value of `tensor(28.)`

#### So, what I am trying to understand why I need to divide the 4-D Tensor by `tensor(28.)` to get the `good_gradient`

If I print bad_gradient, it will be a 4-D Tensor as below

```
tensor([[[[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          ...,
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]]],

          ---
          ---
```

If I print `good_gradient`, the output will be

```
tensor([[[[0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357,  ..., 0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357],
          [0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357,  ..., 0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357],
          [0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357,  ..., 0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357],
          ...,
          [0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357,  ..., 0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357],
          [0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357,  ..., 0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357],
          [0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357,  ..., 0.0357, 0.0357, 0.0357]]],

          ---
          ---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For the line

`good_gradient = torch.ones(*image_shape) / torch.sqrt(image_size)`

First, note the Gradient Penalty term in WGAN is =>

`(norm(gradient(interpolated)) - 1)^2`

And for the Ideal Gradient (i.e. a Good Gradient), this Penalty term would be 0. i.e.  A Good gradient is one which has its gradient_penalty is as close to 0 as possible

This means the following should satisfy, after considering the L2-Norm of the Gradient

##### `(norm(gradient(x')) -1)^2 = 0`

i.e  `norm(gradient(x')) = 1`

i.e. `sqrt(Sum(gradient_i^2) ) = 1`

Now if you just continue simplifying the above (considering how `norm` is calculated, see my note below) math expression, you will end up with

`good_gradient = torch.ones(*image_shape) / torch.sqrt(image_size)`

Since you are passing the `image_shape` as (256, 1, 28, 28) - so  `torch.sqrt(image_size)` in your case  is tensor(28.)

Effectively the above line is dividing each element of A 4-D Tensor like [[[[1., 1. ... ]]]] with a scaler tensor(28.)

---

#### Separately, note how `norm` is calculated

[image]

`torch.norm` without extra arguments performs, what is called a Frobenius norm which is effectively reshaping the matrix into one long vector and returning the 2-norm of that.

Given an M * N matrix, The Frobenius Norm of a matrix is defined as the square root of the sum of the squares of the elements of the matrix.

```
Input: mat[][] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]] 
Output: 5.47723 
sqrt(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2) = sqrt(30) = 5.47723
```